# Isso é um erro no servidor?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysqli, phpmyadmin

desenvolvi uma aplicação na qual no meu servidor local está funcionando perfeitamente. Portanto quando coloco no servidor web está me retornando o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in
```

Alguém sabe me dizer se isso é um erro do servidor web ou não? E se não for como resolvo isso?

Aqui o código de conexão:

```
<?php

$servidor = "local";
$usuario = "usuario";
$senha = "senha";
$tabela = "nomedabase";

$conexao = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $tabela);

if ($conexao->connect_error) {
    die("Erro: " . $conexao->connect_error);
}

$busca = $_POST['palavra'];
$cidade = $_POST ['cidade'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' AND cidade = '$cidade'";
$resultados = $conexao->query($sql);


if ($resultados->num_rows > 0) {
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
        print("<strong>Nome: </strong>" . $linha['nome'] . "</br>");
        print ("<strong>Endereço: </strong>" . $linha['endereco']."</br>");
        if( isset($_POST['cidade']) && $_POST['cidade'] === 'sao-gabriel-da-palha' ) {
            $fromPerson = 'São Gabriel da Palha';
            echo "<strong>Cidade: </strong>".$fromPerson."</br>";
        }
        print ("<strong>Telefone: </strong>" . $linha['telefone']."</br>");
        echo "<strong>email: </strong>". $linha['email']."</br>";
        echo "<hr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nenhum resultado para a sua busca.";
}

$conexao->close();
```

Comment: Teria como vc mostrar o codigo de conexão ?

Comment: editei ai colocando o código de conexão, acredito que esteja tudo ok, pois está funcionando no servidor localhost, apenas no servidor web que está dando esse fatal error

Comment: Já aconteceu bastante comigo quando vou colocar algo no servidor web da erro e no servidor local não... reparei que na verdade era porque no servidor web utilizava outro tipo de barra para criação do caminho dos arquivos... Exemplo:
`wamp/www/meuprojeto/aaaa.php`
no servidor web teria que ficar assim:
`wamp\www\meuprojeto\aaaa.php`

Então o erro pode esta no autoload...

Comment: Mais onde estão essas barras que devo inverter???

Comment: MySQLi é nativo do PHP, então não deve ser erro no *autoload*. O que pode ser é a extensão não estar habilitada no seu servidor. Veja o retorno da função [`phpinfo()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.phpinfo.php) no servidor e verifique se a extensão está instalada.

Comment: O servidor tambem pode esta em `case-sensitive` então a instancia da classe deve ser feita maiusculo e minusculo. Tente assim:
´new MySQLi´

Comment: @EveraldoCosta é tudo minúsculo mesmo: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss veja ai o que me retornou no phpinfo...http://guianortecapixaba.com.br/versao.php

Comment: De fato não parece ter a extensão instalada. Tente entrar com contato com o suporte da hospedagem.

Comment: Ai o que falo com eles? Para instalar a extensão do msqli?? é isso!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Galera a solução foi mudar a versão do PHP, pois estava em 5.2 no servidor web e no local tava 7.0... dai mudei no servidor e resolveu o problema!